# VPS Ubuntu connection timeout when I try connect via IP in browser

Tags: ubuntu, ip, apache-2.4, vps

I have a problem with my VPS. It has installed Apache.
When I trying to connect from specific network (home) I can easily access to it.
When try on another one (for example 3G) it returns 110 - connection timeout after a while.
Another person tried on his and could access, via mobile.

I don't see any specific in access.log, when is timeout. So website wasn't reached.

DNS has only A record.

ufw allow traffic for Apache.

What should I check to find out a problem?

edit: what is more, couldn't ping in networks that couldn't reach website - however using ping.eu I can ping ok, no packet loss. Can ping to ip when in network that could reach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like packets from 'some_problem_place' are not reaching your webserver at all. You can debug this using `tcpdump` (i assume that you know outer network interface on your webserver):

1. On server run `sudo tcpdump -ni "outer inferface" src host "IP of some_problem_place"` . For example: `sudo tcpdump -ni eth0 src host 11.22.33.44`
2. On client try to access your webserver like you did it before

Then

- If `tcpdump` gives you no output then packets are not reaching your webserver. You may call your 3G provider and ask why. They will probably ask you to provide trace. You can prepare it in advance by running: `traceroute "your webserver's IP"` (on unix) or `tracert "your webserver's IP"` (on windows).
- If you see output then you need to find out why webserver doesn't respond. You may start with posting your `httpd.conf` here

Comment: +1 for tcpdump - didn't know about this command! 

However, currently works smoothly, because distro upgraded 15.04->15.10. Shot? apparmor has been updated, maybe was the case...if I run through problem again I will post it.